# Enhancing performance of join query for mapnik using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, mapnik, attribute-joins, optimization

I use mapnik to render map with datasources from a PostGIS database. One query is a join on two table, one with a geometry (a polygon) and the other one with some fields I want to use for rendering. Unfortunately, this query is very slow...

Here is the slow query:

```sql
SELECT table1.id, table1.geometry, table2.fk_table1, table2.field FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.fk_table1)
WHERE table1.geometry && SetSRID('BOX3D(x1 y1, x2 y2)'::box3d,900913);
```

Here is the query plan I got from an EXPLAIN:

```sql
Hash Join  (cost=118896.94..262210.34 rows=27942 width=1099)
    Hash Cond: (table1.id = table2.fk_table1)
    ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..73740.89 rows=4786689 width=16)
    ->  Hash  (cost=113876.63..113876.63 rows=33865 width=1083)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table1  (cost=1112.15..113876.63 rows=33865 width=1083)
```

This query can be faster if the bbox is first applied on table1.geometry. However, mapnik does not help me there. Indeed, mapnik builds a query from a table/subquery by adding a WHERE clause on it

```sql
  SELECT AsBinary("geometry") AS geom
  FROM subquery 
  WHERE "geometry" && SetSRID('BOX3D(x1 y1,x2 y2)'::box3d,900913)
```

With the following subquery:

```sql
( SELECT table1.id, table1.geometry, table2.fk_table1, table2.field FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.fk_table1) ) as subquery
```

Basically, I need to enhance the speed of this query knowing that mapnik will add a where clause on the subquery.

Comment: As Nickas said it, the main issue comes from the seq scan of the table2 even if there is an index on this table. To solve this, I change the parameter random_page_cost to favor the index scan:


    ALTER TABLESPACE pg_global SET ( random_page_cost = 2, seq_page_cost=1);

This solved my performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a bbox anywhere can make the join faster. WHat is needed is a working index on table1.id and table2.fk_table1.

The bbox gist index filter will be more costly than joining on indexed integer columns.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just posted an answer [here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/1080#issuecomment-3946196).